# Wait till program close to continue

Tags: command-line

So im trying to set up emulationstation to run my PS2 games via the retroarch core. I have this

```
C:\Users\VODKAN~1\.emulationstation\systems\RetroArch\retroarch.exe -L C:\Users\VODKAN~1\.emulationstation\systems\RetroArch\cores\pcsx2_libretro.dll "%ROM_RAW%" | taskkill /im cmd.exe
```

Now buy itself in retroarch it works just fine but when launching through ES the closing of the `cmd.exe` triggers ES to pop back up. I've tried `start /B /WAIT` at the front but it ends in the same way. Is it possible to run this command and have it sit idle till the program closes then kill the `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
retroarch.exe -L C:\Users\VODKAN~1\.emulationstation\systems\RetroArch\cores\pcsx2_libretro.dll "%ROM_RAW%" & exit
```

Comment: this still leaves the `cmd.exe` open still needing to be closed.